# Layout editor in Android Studio does not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Whenever I open a layout file in Android Studio, I only see 2 spanner symbols in the layout editor instead of a preview of the UI (except that some UIs are visible, and some are not).

One of the layout editors looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGDlY.jpg), however the second one (which is the landscape version) looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldO18.jpg) - this is also happening when I open other projects. The errors seen in the top right corner are:

1. An error which reads:

```
String index out of range: -1

Error inflating the preview. (Details)

Tip: try to refresh the layout
```

I don't know what this error means; also note that when I click the text that says "refresh" (it is clickable), or when I try to manually refresh the layout, nothing happens.

2. An error which reads:

```
Render problem

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor747.invoke  
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)   
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 

Copy stack to clipboard   

Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

Like the first error, I don't know why this error is present, and I am unable to refresh the layout as it suggests.

3. A notice which reads:

```
Use new Layout Rendering Engine

Click here to enable the new Layout Rendering Engine. If it causes any issue, it can later be disabled using the Settings > Experimental dialog.
```

Firstly, this Rendering Engine is already disabled, additionally, if I enable the engine (or click on "here", which is clickable), then the message changes to read:

```
Rendering errors might be caused by the new Layout Rendering Engine. Disabling it by clicking here may fix the issue. It can later be enabled again using the Settings > Experimental dialog.
```

The XML code for the 2 layout files (which have the same code) is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_8"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_4"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_5"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_6"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_1"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_2"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button1"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_3"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button2"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_0"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button1" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/divide_operator"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/multiply_operator"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/minus_operator"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button3"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/plus_operator"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonEquals"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonEquals"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/dot"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button0"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button0"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/equals_symbol"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonEquals"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonDot"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/buttonDot"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_7"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newNumber"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/newNumber" />

    <Button
            android:text="@string/number_9"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button8" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/result"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor"
            android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/newNumber"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/result"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/result"
            android:autofillHints=""
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/operation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/newNumber"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.298"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button7" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have tried to restart Android Studio, rebuild the project, run Build -> Clean Project, and run File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart, all several times, and I have not been able to fix this. Any help on how to get the layout editor to consistently work for *all* projects would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio twice, and it has not changed anything. I have also tried to copy the layout files in a new project, and I get the exact same errors and issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 4.2 Layout Render Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472956/android-studio-4-2-layout-render-errors)

Comment: @Vaibhav Sorry for the late reply, but thank you - your answer works.