# Android Studio layout rendering issue

Tags: android, android-studio

since the new Android version has been released (currently using 4.2) layout renderer is giving me errors with every single EditText in each of my layout. Below an example. Every single resource exist.
If I comment the xml of the EditText the error disappear.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sftTag"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/sft"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textColorHint="#eee"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/scanCameraButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />
```

I've also disabled and enabled the newest rendering engine several times, but nothing changed.
Below the stack trace of the error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor547.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:354)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:74)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:209)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:127)
    ... 30 more
```

and the other error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:697)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:99)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:55)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:51)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView.<init>(MockView.java:47)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:324)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:354)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

EDIT: added drawble xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#919191"/>
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dip"
    android:topRightRadius="5dip"/>
```

```
<string name="sft">SFT</string>
```

How can I detect where is located the issue?

Thanks

Comment: The issue might be due to the hint or the background drawable, can you add those to the description

Comment: @SreehariK Added the drawable and the hint string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 4.2 Layout Render Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472956/android-studio-4-2-layout-render-errors)

Comment: @Vaibhav the line suggested by the dupe target does not appear in this code.