# Error while inflating layout Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

The last days i'm facing issues with layout rendering in android studio layout preview.
I have already tried clear caches, deleting all strings from xml file, but this didn't help. I dont have any otehr ideas.

I will appreciate any help. Thank u.

I'm getting 2 errors

**First stack trace**

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor588.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:325)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:369)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:710)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:865)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:174)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1024)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:809)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:778)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:847)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:74)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:209)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:127)
```

**Second error**

```
String index out of range: -1
```

**And there is layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapActivityLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".ui.mapactivity.MapsActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                tools:context=".ui.mapactivity.MapsActivity" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutServerSync"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonServerSync"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_sync"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_select_farm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/field_style_3"
                android:maxWidth="150dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_farms_container"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:maxWidth="174dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bt_show_farms"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_farm"
                        android:elevation="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:maxWidth="150dp"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/farm"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_farm_filter"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:autofillHints=""
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorButtonsFirst"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:hint="@string/filter"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/iv_hide_farms"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_up_chevron"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rv_farms_list"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_select_field"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/field_style_3"
                android:maxWidth="224dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cv_select_farm"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_fields_container"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bt_show_fields"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_field_with_icon"
                        android:elevation="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_fields_fiter"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:autofillHints=""
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorButtonsFirst"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:hint="@string/filter"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/iv_hide_fields"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_up_chevron"
                            android:visibility="gone"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rv_fields_list"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cv_select_map_type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/field_style_3"
                android:maxWidth="200dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraintLayoutServerSync">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ll_map_type_container"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bt_show_map_types"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/button_map_type"
                        android:elevation="10dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rv_map_types"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonZoomPlus"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_map_zoom_in"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonZoomMinus"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_map_zoom_out"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
                    android:id="@+id/floatingActionMenu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    app:menu_colorNormal="@color/app_accent"
                    app:menu_colorPressed="@color/dark_accent"
                    app:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_speedometer"
                    app:menu_labels_position="right"
                    app:menu_shadowRadius="5dp"
                    app:menu_showShadow="true">

                    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/fab_clear_selected_fields"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
                        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/app_accent"
                        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/dark_accent"
                        app:fab_label="@string/clear_selected_fields" />

                    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/fab_measure_selected_fields"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
                        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/app_accent"
                        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/dark_accent"
                        app:fab_label="@string/measure_selected_fields" />

                </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayoutMapActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also post Your MapsActivity class?

Comment: But error are only in the android studio layout preview. The app builds and runs normally. And I can`t post code from the activity, because it goes under NDA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 4.2 Layout Render Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472956/android-studio-4-2-layout-render-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update  following Lines from your XML Layout file to proper autofillHints or remove the line

```
android:autofillHints=""
```

Blank autofillHints are not working in Android Studio 4.2 Layout Preview

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your android version on your designed preview. Rendering problem caused
your designed preview to use higher API level than your current android API level.

[image: check out highlighted text]

Comment: didnt help, sorry

Comment: @Martijn Pieters What to do When two Different Question Have Same Answers  In this case the workaround is working in multiple scenerios

Comment: @ЮрійЯремчук Remove Blank AutofiilHints in your Layout

Comment: @Vaibhav thank u, this helped, add your comment as answer so i can mark it