# Android Studio 4.2.2 activity_main.xml file not showing Designs

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm facing an Issue on Android Studio 4.2.2. I can see code on XML but I'm unable to get designs. I tried everything changing API levels and Using New and Old Layout Rendering Engine. Invalidating Cache and Restarting, But Nothing Works. Find the Below image and code for reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enter_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="@string/enter_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_name"
        android:labelFor="@id/enter_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:autofillHints=""
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enter_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4e3r.png)

Comment: Well, the image indicates that there are two errors. Have you looked closer at them and tried to fix them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 4.2 Layout Render Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472956/android-studio-4-2-layout-render-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design is not showing because the `android:autofillHints=""` is empty, setting a value should fix it. E.g: `android:autofillHints="name"` or `android:autofillHints="username"`.